# Tk Canvas(Python) : How to get the size (width, height) and coordinates of the entire range that Canvas can move with the scroll bar

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, scroll, tk-toolkit

I want to get the canvas area, coordinates and width and height that can be moved with the scroll bar.
That is the part in red in the explanation image.

Is there no choice but to calculate from Scrollbar.get()? I think that an error will occur in this calculation.

[image: Canvas illustration]

**Add Information**

I want to properly change the canvas display area and scroll bar when the widget to be operated on the canvas is changed by key operation or button operation and the widget exists outside the displayed canvas area.
Also, when I move the widget by mouse dragging it outside the canvas display area, I want the canvas display area to follow the display area smoothly.

The sources for moving the canvas area by mouse drag are as follows:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class TkCanvas():
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas_w, self.canvas_h = 600, 600

        self.interval = 1000

        self.ldrag = False
        self.select_cube = None
        self.cube = list()
        self.create_cube_coord = [0,0,0,0]
        self.sx, self.sy = None, None

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=self.canvas_w, height=self.canvas_h,
            relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=2, bg='green')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= tk.N+tk.E+tk.W+tk.S)

        self.xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)

        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)

        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)

        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>',self.left_click)
        self.canvas.bind('<Motion>',self.move)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.left_release)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>',self.right_click)
        self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>',self.wheel)

        self.root.after(self.interval,self.run)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def run(self):

        self.root.after(self.interval,self.run)
        return

    def left_click(self,event):
        canvas = self.canvas

        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        oid_list = canvas.find_overlapping(x,y,x,y)

        if oid_list:
            oid_list = list(oid_list)
            sorted(oid_list,reverse=True)
            self.select_cube = oid_list[-1]
            canvas.itemconfigure(
                self.select_cube,
                fill='skyblue',
                outline='blue',
                )
            self.sx, self.sy = x, y
        else:
            self.ldrag = True
            self.create_cube_coord = [x,y,x,y]

            cube = canvas.create_rectangle(
                self.create_cube_coord,
                fill='pink',
                outline='red',
                )
            self.cube.append(cube)

        return

    def right_click(self,event):
        canvas = self.canvas

        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        if not self.ldrag:
            oid_list = canvas.find_overlapping(x,y,x,y)
            if oid_list:
                oid_list = list(oid_list)
                sorted(oid_list,reverse=True)
                sel = oid_list[-1]
                canvas.delete(sel)
                index = self.cube.index(sel)
                self.cube.pop(index)
                self.canvas_scroll_regset()

        return

    def move(self,event):
        canvas = self.canvas

        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        if self.ldrag:
            px, py = self.create_cube_coord[0],self.create_cube_coord[1]

            sx, sy = min(x,px),min(y,py)
            ex, ey = max(x,px),max(y,py)
            if self.cube.append:
                canvas.coords(self.cube[-1],sx, sy, ex, ey)
                self.canvas_scroll_regset()
        else:
            if self.select_cube:
                dx = x - self.sx
                dy = y - self.sy
                canvas.move(self.select_cube,dx,dy)
                self.sx, self.sy = x, y

                self.canvas_scroll_regset()

        return

    def wheel(self,event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
        return

    def canvas_scroll_regset(self):
        canvas = self.canvas

        box_coords = canvas.bbox("all")

        if box_coords:
            ox0, oy0, ox1, oy1 = box_coords

            sx = canvas.winfo_x()
            sy = canvas.winfo_y()
            sw = canvas.winfo_width()
            sh = canvas.winfo_height()

            cx0 = canvas.canvasx(sx)
            cy0 = canvas.canvasy(sy)
            cx1 = canvas.canvasx(sx)+sw-1
            cy1 = canvas.canvasy(sy)+sh-1

            if cx0 < 0:
                cx1 -= cx0
                cx0 -= cx0
            if cy0 < 0:
                cy1 -= cy0
                cy0 -= cy0

            if ox0 < cx0:
                sc_x0 = ox0
            else:
                sc_x0 = cx0

            if oy0 < cy0:
                sc_y0 = oy0
            else:
                sc_y0 = cy0

            if ox1 > cx1:
                sc_x1 = ox1
            else:
                sc_x1 = cx1

            if oy1 > cy1:
                sc_y1 = oy1
            else:
                sc_y1 = cy1

            if (sc_x0, sc_y0, sc_x1, sc_y1) != (cx0, cy0, cx1, cy1):
                canvas['scrollregion'] = (sc_x0, sc_y0, sc_x1, sc_y1)
            else:
                canvas['scrollregion'] = (0,0,0,0)

            x_f, x_l = self.xscroll.get()
            y_f, y_l = self.yscroll.get()

            canvas_w, canvas_h = sw/(x_l-x_f)-1, sh/(y_l-y_f)-1

            if int(canvas_w) > int(sw):
                if x_f > 0.0:
                    canvas.xview(tk.MOVETO,0.0)
                elif x_l < 0.99:
                    canvas.xview(tk.MOVETO,1.0)
                print('x:',x_f, x_l)
            if int(canvas_h) > int(sh):
                print('y:',y_f, y_l)


    def left_release(self,event):
        canvas = self.canvas

        if self.ldrag:
            canvas.itemconfigure(
                self.cube[-1],
                fill='lightgreen',
                outline='green',
                )
            self.ldrag = False
        else:
            if self.select_cube:
                canvas.itemconfigure(
                    self.select_cube,
                    fill='lightgreen',
                    outline='green',
                    )
                self.select_cube = None
        return

t = TkCanvas()
```

The movement of the canvas area is rattling.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to do. What error are you expecting. What have you tried?

Comment: Excuse me.
I edited the content of the question and added it.

Comment: In the added source code, moving the canvas display area is implemented only by horizontal dragging.